# Insert current datetime with SQL statement using fastcsv/MySQL and Node.js

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

I'm using bezcoders code to get the contents of a CSV file into a MySQL database, but there are no dates or times in the CSV.

This is the code I'm using within node.js:

```html
const fs = require("fs");
const mysql = require("mysql");
const fastcsv = require("fast-csv");

let stream = fs.createReadStream("bezkoder.csv");
let csvData = [];
let csvStream = fastcsv
  .parse()
  .on("data", function(data) {
    csvData.push(data);
  })
  .on("end", function() {
    // remove the first line: header
    csvData.shift();

    // create a new connection to the database
    const connection = mysql.createConnection({
      host: "localhost",
      user: "root",
      password: "123456",
      database: "testdb"
    });

    // open the connection
    connection.connect(error => {
      if (error) {
        console.error(error);
      } else {
        let query =
          "INSERT INTO category (id, name, description, created_at) VALUES ?";
        connection.query(query, [csvData], (error, response) => {
          console.log(error || response);
        });
      }
    });
  });

stream.pipe(csvStream);
```

I believe adding this to the SQL statement could fix:

`var newDate = new Date().toLocaleString();`
But I don't know the correct syntax, because `fast-csv` represnets the values as "?" or [csvData]. This makes it a parameterized query.

So how do I add a newDate value into the `created_at` column for each row?

Comment: Your table must contain a column for this date. If it exists, you must simply alter the properties of the column and add `DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` to its options. After this you do not need to set the value to this column, and even do not need to mention it in the insertion - the value will be assigned automatically and hiddenly. Of course if this column not exists yet you must add it with mentioned option. And similar option `ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` exists too, and it may be set in addition (or maybe you'll add 2 columns, 1st with only DEFAULT and 2nd with both options).

Comment: omg. didnt thought about that! Yes that solves my problem. thanks

Comment: `csvData.push(data.concat('2021-08-13 01:02:03'))` should add the extra column to `csvData`.

Comment: Depending on the details, you can probably provide `NOW()` as the value of the column.